# How do I use camel-ddb to persist json payload

Tags: apache-camel, amazon-dynamodb

I have created and table in dynamodb (EU-WEST-1) and I have created a camel route to put a json payload into the table.

My route looks like this:

```
String dynamoDbEndpoint = String.format("aws-ddb://tablename?accessKey=%s&secretKey=RAW(%s)&tableName=tablename&amazonDdbEndpoint=dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com",awsAccessKey,awsSecretKey);
from("direct:ipg-queue").to(dynamoDbEndpoint)
```

I get the error message:

> com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: 1 validation error detected: Value null at 'item' failed to satisfy constraint: Member must not be null (Service: AmazonDynamoDB; Status Code: 400; Error Code: ValidationException; Request ID: 0AVSR54LRTOG3U0TTC5B1QO4KBVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)

An example payload is:

```
{"accountNumber":"123456789","customerName":"John Smith","id":"8422b9e0-739b-4d19-9291-037b68344068"}
```

Represented as a String.

I'm doing something stupid, but can't figure it out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out I was being stupid. You just need to set the CamelAwdDbItem header in the exchange. I added the following process block to my route before the dynamo db endpoint and away I went...

```
.unmarshal()
.json(JsonLibrary.Gson, Map.class)
.process((Exchange exchange) -> {
    Map body = (Map) exchange.getIn()
                             .getBody();

    Map<String, AttributeValue> newBody = new HashMap();

    for(Object key : body.keySet()) {
        newBody.put(key.toString(), new AttributeValue(body.get(key).toString()));
    }

    exchange.getIn().setHeader("CamelAwsDdbItem", newBody);
})
```

I also put `&operation=PutItem` onto the end of the endpoint definition.